# Change preview Image after clicking a button on krajee file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many records in a table in my page, each of them has an "edit" button, it gets all the data in relation of that record from server, and then it fills the form next to the table.

Thing is, Im using Krajee File Input, and I can't seem to change the preview image to the one I previously uploaded in server. When I click "Edit", 
It should change the preview image everytime an edit button of any record is clicked, and show the image of that record in the File Input Plug-in.

First question: Is that even possible?

Second and last, I leave my JS code, initialisation:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() 
{
  $('#photo').fileinput(
                      {
                       overwriteInitial: true,
                       maxFileSize: 100,
                       showRemove:false
                       }                           
                       );    
 });
```

The Edit function that inside has the FileInput code part.

```
$("#photo").fileinput('refresh', 
                         {
                             initailPreview:
                             [
                                 '<img src="../img/Legacy.jpg" class="file-preview-image">'
                             ],
                             showUpload:false 
                         }
                         );
```

For what I have seen so far, It refreshes the Plug-in, it removes the "Upload" button, but the image doesn't show.
The images only appear when I add them in the "OnReady".
And for practicall matters I just used any image stored in my project (Legacy.jpg), to see if it works.

Comment: you have a spelling error in the second code block: `initailPreview` should probably be `initialPreview`

Comment: Yeah, I came to realize a few minutes ago, I lost nearly three hours with this T.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god, it was "Initial" not "Initail".